# How to parse array elements?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I tried to parse a string array using the code below but the required data never printed! could any one tell me how to fix it ?Thanks

$data Array structure :

```
Array
(
    [js] => Array
        (
            [total_items] => 20
            [max_page_items] => 2
            [selected_item] => 0
            [cur_page] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                        [tmp] => 1
                        [name] => mango
                        [abc] => abcd4 http://mysite/items/1234
                        [number] => 1123
                        [itemCategory_title] => fruits
                        [logo] => 2123.png
                        [itemCategory_id] => 90
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                        [tmp] => 0
                        [name] => cherry
                        [abc] => abcd4 http://mysite/items/1235
                        [number] => 1124
                        [itemCategory_title] => fruits
                        [logo] => 2124.png
                        [itemCategory_id] => 
                        )

               )

         )

    [text] => no error
)
```

php code:

```
<?
$code2 = stripslashes($_POST['outputtext']);

$data = json_decode($code2);

foreach( $data as $item ) {
  echo $item['tmp'];
  echo $item['name'];
  echo $item['abc'];
  echo $item['number'];
  echo $item['itemCategory_title'];
  echo $item['log'];
  echo $item['itemCategory_id'];    
}

?>
```

Comment: `foreach( $data['js']['data'] as $item ) {`

Comment: First, json_decode returns an object, not an array. Unless you pass true as the second object that is. Both would work though, if using an object, you need to use the arrow operator like `$item->tmp`. Second, the `data` key is under the `js` key. So you need to loop over `$data['js']['data']` (or `$data->js->data` if you leave off that second argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
foreach ($data['js']['data'] AS $item)
```

because the array is nested several levels down in `$data`.

Note that you need to call `json_decode($code2, true)` to get an associative array like that. By default, it returns an object, not an array, so you would do:

```
foreach ($data->js->data as $item) {
    echo $item->tmp;
    echo $item->name;
    ...
}
```

Comment: We get questions like this on a daily basis. I don't understand how you can look at that array structure and not see immediately that the array you want is nested, not at the top level.